# Is there a way to execute a method of a service using a command with nestjs?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I need to execute a method of a service without using api rest, that is, execute it through a single execution command

Comment: probably? I didn't get what do you meant by _execution command_ but this: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/events or this: https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/cqrs might help you

Comment: to run it directly without using a controller, something similar to an npm command

Answer (score 2):

looks like you want to build a command line interface (CLI) or just a script. This is feasible with nestjs standalone app like any nodejs app, as the docs shows here: https://docs.nestjs.com/standalone-applications

you can also use a 3rd-party package like `nest-commander`, as the docs shows here: https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/nest-commander

I suggest you to dive into the official docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nestjs repl. Follow this [link](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/repl) for more info.